# Flow not running in apex test on deploy

Tags: flow

We are trying to deploy a set metadata that includes apex tests and some flows. The flows are autolaunched by process builder when someone inserts a new record and create an additional record for use. We have a set of apex tests that utilise this flow's functionality and are failing in the validation claiming list has no rows for assignment, i.e. the flow is not running and creating those additional records.

We have tried adding the flowDefinition files and updating to v35 but the deployment tool in Eclipse is saying that the flowDefinition files are not a valid metadata type for the destination org. Any ideas?

Comment: Is the behaviour same with Force.com Migration or ANT tool .Might be a bug and worth trying with metadata API and then raising case with support

Comment: Happening in Eclipse, ANT Migration tool and MavensMate. Will see if support can help out in the background

Answer (score 1):

So it turns out that flows are always deployed in the status of inactive and so any classes that rely upon the outcome of flows for tests will fail.

[This idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DrprAAC) would sort this out if it gets selected.